# How to stop dialogs telling me to turn on the ability of Google apps to access my location?

Tags: google

This phone I have been using for years and flashing it with different ROMs, mostly CM. However, I think at the switch from CM 10.2 to CM11 it started giving me this insanely annoying message:

> In a previous version of android, you turned off the ability for
>   Google apps to access your location. Turn it back on for all Google
>   apps ?

Sometimes it just keeps throwing it to my face at every 5-10 seconds, making my device quite hard to use (as if it was not already).

The only options are "Not now" and "Yes". I have root, so, if anyone knows how to blast this nuisance away please let me know.

**Note**: Choosing "Yes" is not an option. Only options for me are either "No, never" (missing from the UI popup) or delete the Google bloatware from it altogether.

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't or don't wanna choose it? If you don't wanna, then I suggest delete the bloatware. (If you choose yes, and then later disable the location, it won't trouble you again.) It's Google Settings that asks it, and the pop-up can be found in CM12 as well.

Comment: @Firelord Choose yes and disable the location ? How do I do the second part ? Are you referring to the Location settings screen ?

Answer (score 0):

[image: dialog screenshot]

I believe that the text in the dialog has been changed with newer versions of Google Play Services, but it still pops up, annoyingly, if you disable WiFi scanning under location settings. I haven't personally tried this Xposed module, but I think that it accomplishes what you want (Deny Location Consent): http://repo.xposed.info/module/org.brainkiller.xposed.denylocationconsent

Note: Since you mentioned that you use CyanogenMod, I assume you have the ability to install Xposed if it isn't installed already.